# Are the complex conjugate representations $e,\bar e$ and $d,\bar d$ for $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ inequivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ be the complex Lie algebra of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})_\mathbb{R}$ be its realification; that is $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})_\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ considered as a real Lie algebra.

Let $d$ be an irrep of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $e$ an irrep of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})_\mathbb{R}$. Define the complex conjugate representations $\bar{d}$ and $\bar{e}$  in the [usual way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_representation).

Am I right in thinking that $d$ and $\bar{d}$ are equivalent representations, which $e$ and $\bar{e}$ are inequivalent? My reasoning is as follows.

The irreps of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ are the spin-$j$ representations, unique in each dimension. The irreps of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})_\mathbb{R}$ are the restrictions of the irreps of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})\oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$, which are uniquely labelled by $(j_1,j_2)$, with the $(j_1,j_2)$ representation conjugate to the $(j_2,j_1)$ representation.

Further I assume that this reasoning can be extended to any complex (perhaps semisimple?) Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Would this be a fair conclusion?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @rschwieb: I didn't say that $e$ had to be a real representation. Real Lie algebras can happily have complex representations. One then uses the second definition of the three on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: And thanks for pointing me to the second definition... I can't believe I missed it...

Comment: @rschwieb: No - you can have complex representations that are only $\mathbb{R}$-linear; for example the $(j_1,j_2)$ representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})_\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What do you mean "No"? That's exactly what my point is :P I think perhaps I need to see how you are using these two terms though... it sounds like we might be using the words in different ways.

Comment: Yes - that's right. Sorry I was unclear! To my knowledge there's no better way to phrase it. I take the convention that a $k$-representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ is a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on some $k$-vector space. That is it's a $l$-linear homomorphism, where $l$ is the underlying field of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: OK, i had been taking "R/C" representation to mean that the corresponding homomorphism was also R/C linear, but now I think I see you mean it to just indicate that it goes into $M_n(R)$ or $M_n(C)$ respectively. Thanks for your patience. Nixing the obsolete comments.

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

1. Well, the main point is that that the finite-dimensional representations of the [complex Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_Lie_group) $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ (and its corresponding complex Lie algebra $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$) by definition have to be [complex manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_manifold). In particular, the representation maps should be holomorphic maps between complex manifolds. This rules out the [complex conjugate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_representation) $\bar{d}$ from the very beginning.
2. Yes, $e$ and $\bar{e}$ are [inequivalent representations](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_linear_representations).